# SearchView personalizado

Tags: android, android-layout

Preciso fazer um searchView como esse:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso colocar o icon branco e o hint também.

Comment: Você chegou a iniciar algum código? poste ele também, fica mais fácil pra ajudar

Comment: Praticamente nada:
<SearchView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/search"
            android:queryHint="@string/search"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:searchHintIcon="@drawable/ic_busca_menu"/>

Comment: Carlos, deixei uma resposta abaixo com um exemplo de código que eu uso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pra fazer bem customizado assim, eu aconselho fazer um EditText.

Exemplo:

```
<EditText
      android:id="@+id/home_search"
      android:hint="pesquisar por nome ou profissão"
      android:textSize="15sp"
      android:inputType="textCapSentences"
      android:textColor="@android:color/white"
      android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
      android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
      android:drawablePadding="8dp"
      android:paddingLeft="24dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
      android:background="@android:color/black"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="45dp"
      android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
      android:imeActionLabel="Search"/>
```

Esse será o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ai no Java, você declara o EditText normalmente e adiciona um **setOnEditorActionListener** nele

Exemplo:

```
EditText home_search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.home_search);
home_search.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH ||
                        actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||
                        actionId == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {

                    String searchTerm = home_search.getText().toString();

                    if(searchTerm != null && searchTerm.length() > 2){
                        metodoQueRealizaABusca(searchTerm);
                        home_search.setText("");
                    }else{
                         Toast.makeText(this, "Digite pelo menos 3 letras para buscar",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Nesse esquema que eu uso, o usuário tem que digitar no minimo 3 letras para que consiga fazer a busca.

E a busca ficará dentro do método **metodoQueRealizaABusca(String searchTerm)** onde ele irá receber o **searchTerm** como parâmetro.